# Visual Databindings in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, data-binding, delphi-xe6

Is there a way to use visual databindings with my own custom units?

[image: bindings]

I would like to be able to bind a form property to a property of a class in my own unit.

i.e.:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type
  TMyClass = class
    strict private
      fMyTextField : String;
    public
      property MyTextField : String read fMyTextField write fMyTextField;
    published
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the property should be public or published

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong and what I really want is to create a custom data source. I'm not sure because I'm not familiar with databindings.

Comment: Do you want to create a dataaware component ? Here is a link with an example :  http://delphidabbler.com/tips/194

Comment: I'd like to be able to separate the form controls from the application logic. I want to have a separate View and View-Model, as in the Model View View-Model (MVVM) design patern

Comment: I removed the Pascal tag. Pascal doesn't have data bindings, and there is no Pascal XE6. Delphi is a specific language and IDE.